# regEx.test(string) does not work in IE but works fine in Chrome, Safari, FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, internet-explorer

I'm loading content via JSON/JSONP from another (parent) site and displaying it locally. The following function hijacks link click events, checks to see if the link points to the parent site, strips the parent site URL from the link, and runs a function to load a news article based on the link URL.

This works fine in all but IE. The issue is with this line:

```
if(regex.test(href)) {
```

If I comment that out, everything works just fine. However, that conditional check is necessary to ensure that we don't hijack links to external sites, i.e., nytimes.com.

I'm stuck as to how to proceed here and am unable to figure out whether this is actually an IE bug or if there's a problem with the regex, or perhaps with how the HREF is being collected? Any insight would be helpful. Full function below.

```
function hijackURLs() {
    // hijack link click events
    $("#news-archive, #news-story").on("click", "a", function(evt) {

        var regex = /http:\/\/parent-site.com\//
            , href = $(this).attr("href");

        // make sure the link matches our regex
        // this isn't working in IE for some reason
        if(regex.test(href)) {

            evt.preventDefault();

            // replace the href with hashtag
            href = href.replace( regex, '#' ).split( '\/#more-' )[0];

            // change the url without a page refresh and add a history entry.
            history.pushState(null, null, href);

            // load the content
            showArticle( href, _news );

        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** I'm rephrasing here. The line mentioned above does not throw an error in IE; it just does not work in IE. The href does not pass the regex.test(), thus the string does not get replaced, and the function to load the article content in place does not get called.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the string in the  `href` variable?

Comment: @Matt : I'm supporting IE9+

Comment: @Oriol : sample href is http://parent-site.com/news/continuing-education-road-trip

Comment: What happens if you only run `/http:\/\/parent-site.com\//.test("http://parent-site.com/news/#continuing-education-road-trip")`?

Comment: @Oriol It just points to the content on the parent site rather than loading it in place.

Comment: Yes, but does it throw an error?

Comment: @Oriol No, no error. But it still doesn't work; the condition is not passed and the link clicks through to the parent site. What should happen is that if the reg ex matches / returns true, the href should be trimmed and pushed to the history, and the related article should be loaded in place.

Comment: I've tested this in IE11 and IE8, and I've been unable to reproduce the issue (it matches in both cases). In my test case I've had to explicitly call `hijackURLs()`. How is the function invoked in your code?

Comment: @Oriol In the code, there is a test for history capability via Modernizr. If true: hijackURLs() is called. In IE9, when I call `hijackURLs()` outside of any condition, nothing happens—the link neither loads in place nor loads the parent site.

Comment: the regex doesn't seems to be an issue, I tested it on http://regexr.com/3aglc with Win7 using IE9 and IE10 and the pattern worked just fine.